# Debugger Visualizer not working? Have i incorrectly registered it?

Tags: .net, visualizer, debuggervisualizer

I have created a debugger visualizer in VS2008. There are two classes i've made, in the same .dll :-

- BinaryDataDebuggerVisualizer
- ImageDebuggerVisualizer

The image one works fine (eg. the magnify glass appears in debug mode) but not for the byte[] one (BinaryDataDV). What my visualizer does is display the binary data as an image in a modal window (if the data is a legit image). I compiled to code in Release mode, then dropped the .dll into C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Visualizers

this is the code that i used to 'define' the vis...

using

```
System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
using Foo.DebuggerVisualizers;  

[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(
    typeof (BinaryDataDebuggerVisualizer),
    typeof (VisualizerObjectSource),
    Target = typeof (byte[]),
    Description = "Binary Data to Image Visualizer")]

namespace Foo.DebuggerVisualizers
{
    public class BinaryDataDebuggerVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService,
           IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            ... my code in here
        }
     }
}
```

I've made a unit test in the debugger visualizer solution, which fires up and test the code .. which it correctly shows a legit (and also illegal) image files. so i believe the code is ok.

When i'm in my real solution, this is what i'm doing (where i expect the magnify glass to show, when i'm hovering over the variable in debug mode).

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("Chick.jpg");
```

then i hover over the variable `data` when i've paused the code while debugging, on that line (using a breakpoint).

No hourglass :(

anyone have any ideas to what is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.  There is a limitation in the Debugger Visualizer framework that prevents them from functioning on array types or object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx

Quote from the page:

> "You can write a custom visualizer for an object of any managed class
> except for Object or Array"

Comment: Thanks heaps for the answer. Wowzer! out of all the viz's i tried to do, it was one of them that wasn't supported! so lol :P thanks heaps JaredPar for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is described here: https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/01/ written by Josh Smith.

In that article he was describing the use of a particular visualizer (called Mole, which no longer seems to exist); I've cut down that text somewhat to just leave the general purpose concepts.

> ...
>
> The crux of the matter is that Visual Studio will not allow us to
> apply the `DebuggerVisualizer` attribute to [a custom visualizer] and
> specify that it works for any object that descends from `System.Object`.
> ... I figured out a simple way to work around this artificial
> limitation imposed by Visual Studio.
>
> Visual Studio has no qualms with allowing us to specify that [a custom
> visualizer] can be used to visualize a `System.WeakReference` object.
> Since `WeakReference` is basically just a thin wrapper around any
> object, we use `WeakReference` as a Trojan horse to smuggle any object
> past the Visual Studio sentries... Once [the custom visualizer] gets a
> hold of the `WeakReference` we wrapped around the object that we
> actually want to visualize, it unwraps the object and displays it in
> the UI, throwing away the `WeakReference` in the process. Keep in mind
> that we are only using `WeakReference` as a container to smuggle any
> object into [the visualizer], we are not using that class for its
> intended and documented purpose.
>
> So that’s all well and good, but it would be a real nuisance if you
> had to stop your debugging session just to edit your code and create
> these `WeakReferences`... That’s where the Watch window enters the
> picture. You can create a `WeakReference` in the Watch window, and pass
> the object to visualize into its constructor. Here’s an example...:
>
> [image]
>
> Once the `WeakReference` has been created in the Watch window, I can
> simply click on the magnifying glass icon to open [the visualizer].