# Visual studio custom visualizer target type for user defined classes and collections

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, debuggervisualizer

I have written one custom visualizer for visual studio, which works on class (user defined) and collection (generics).

But its now showing in application. i have put the dlls on proper place and thats not a issue...

the issue is its Type defining.

I have put below attribute on visualizer class.

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(
typeof(ObjectToI.WriteICodeFromObject),
typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
Target = typeof(System.Object),**here i am not sure what to put as my visualizer will work for both user defined classes and generics collections.**
Description = "Object To I Code Visualizer")]
```

please suggest what should i put in target type as my visualizer will work for user defined classes and lists/IEnumerable.

I have tried System.Object but that is not working

I have tried `System.Collections.Generic.IList` but that also not working, even not on List..

please suggest...

Comment: Why do you think the target is the problem? If you use `System.Object` you should be able to open the visualizer for any object.

Comment: @AdiLester: Because its not working with that..looks like its not supporting it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506819/debugger-visualizer-for-any-icollection-and-icollectiont-types

Comment: If I remember correctly, you cannot set Object to be your Visualizer target. You need to be more specific than that. The following visualizer works on lists, you can probably find what you need here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25268/A-Generic-List-and-Dictionary-Debugger-Visualizer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify the target type as `Target = typeof(System.Object)` in your code. Since an object of type 'Object' and 'Array' cannot be visualized.

From MSDN :
*You can write a custom visualizer for an object of any managed class except for **Object** or **Array**.*  Link : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx
][1]

For lists/IEnumerable :

Specify the target as `Target = typeof(List<>)` or `Target = typeof(ObservableCollection<>)`

For UserDefined Class :

Specify the target as `Target = typeof(MyClass)`

or

replace the Target with `TargetTypeName = "MyNamespace.MyClass, MyNamespace"`

This will work.

Comment: +1 - Nudged me in the right direction for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. I ended up using `Target = typeof(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<,>)`